# Why filter does not work when getting result from php file using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to filter data by check box and search field. Code is working fine when i'm giving the static json array to `$scope.students` variable but it does not working and nothing showing when i'm getting same json array through php file using `$http.get("data.php").then(function(response) {...});`

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="findname" placeholder="Search Name">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tech in technologyArray">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tech.on">{{tech.u_proffession}}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="stu in students | filter:{u_name: findname} | customFilter:(technologyArray|filter:{on:true})">
      <strong>Name :{{stu.u_name}}</strong> ({{stu.u_proffession}})
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### JS

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.technologyArray = [{
      u_proffession: "developer",
      on: false
    }, {
      u_proffession: "driver",
      on: false
    }];

    $scope.students = [
        {"u_name":"adrian","u_mail":"Aenean.sed@ut.net","u_images":"11.jpg","u_proffession":"developer"},
        {"u_name":"shelley","u_mail":"urna@In.ca","u_images":"11.jpg","u_proffession":"developer"},
        {"u_name":"nasim","u_mail":"sed@acurna.edu","u_images":"11.jpg","u_proffession":"driver"}
    ];
  })
  .filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(input, techs) {
      if(!techs || techs.length === 0) return input;
      var out = [];
      angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
        angular.forEach(techs, function(tech) {
          if (item.u_proffession === tech.u_proffession) {
            out.push(item);
          }
        });
      });
      return out;
    }
  });
```

Above code is working fine as i want but i wanted to fetch the data from php file now its working with static json data. So when i'm adding below script instead of static json array then it does not working.

```
  controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    ....
    $http.get("data.php").then(function(response) {
        $scope.students= response.data.records
    });
  })
```

There is same json array in the `data.php`

```
{"records":[{"u_name":"adrian","u_mail":"abc@gmail.net","u_proffession":"developer"},{...}]}
```

Can anyone guide me how can i fix the issue. I would like appreciate if someone guide me regarding this. Thank You.

Comment: Your request is looking fine. Can you please make plunker for your problem?

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `response` is? Is it a string or an object?

Comment: you're settings $scope.students to respons.data.records, check if that's a syntax error. plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9LyPEquWaymxVpkPyY2x?p=preview

Comment: @XerenNarcy yes i checked it is object